# Is it possible to do a kind of Link / Button style using CSS with special effects like shadows, outlining of text, and/or gradient?

Tags: css, graphics

Is it possible to make such buttons (http://img225.imageshack.us/img225/6452/buttonslw9.jpg) using CSS? It should be Menu, and PHP would just feed the text to html/css and css should take care of the design.

Maybe I want too much out of CSS - especially with that red outline of the text.. ? Any ideas how i can achieve such results without doing those buttons manually in Graphical Editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pure" solution is possible in latest Safari with `text-shadow`, `-webkit-text-stroke` and `-webkit-gradient` properties (explained in [Safari blog](http://webkit.org/blog/175/introducing-css-gradients/)).

You could also use SVG + CSS `background-image` in Opera 9.5 and Safari.

A practical solution that works in more than a couple of cutting-edge browsers is to generate images on the server side with [GD library](http://php.net/gd).

Comment: would GD library do what i need?

Answer (score 0):

There is no cross-browser way to do this (as you said, especially with the red text outline), but the Webkit and Gecko teams are implementing some cool CSS things like gradients embossing with experimental CSS properties.

You might see what jQuery can do for you. It does some pretty cool CSS-like things that go beyond CSS.